# Control robot by using keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, raspberry-pi, controls, keyboard-events

I am new to Python and raspberry pi, I have created a wheeled robot and codes for forwards, backward, turn left and turn right! However every time I want to execute a differant script I have to open a new code and run it(eg open the file for forwards, then open the file for left etc etc.)

How do I use the the keyboard arrows to execute parts of the script?

I want to be able to press the up button and the robot move forward, then release the up button and the robot stop, then press the left arrow key and the robot turn left until I release the key etc.

Iv tried tons of forums and threads but they all relate to differant codes (iv found how to use keyboard events for turtle but they don't work on i2c or gpio)

Can anybody help me
I bet there's a real simple command code but I don't know what it is or where to find it!

I'm using adafruit motor hat with raspberry pi to power the motors if this makes a difference

Comment: In your Python code, you would have an infinite loop, or that closes when a certain key is pressed. Then you would grab the key pressed and use it in a switch or if/else and put your code from forward, backward, etc.. under the appropriate condition.

Comment: How do I grab the key presses? Do you have any examples or even just the bit of code?

Comment: You already said yourself you are doing it using multiple files. Combine those file into one.

Comment: Yea but how do I use a keyboard to execute differant files?

Comment: I know it's probly a really simple code like key.press (up) = python forward.py etc but I don't know the actual python command for using the arrow keys (or any keys) in real time to execute a file or module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one file for this. Make a new file.

You will need a infinite loop, I will suggest using a `while(true)` loop. You then need

```
if(/*key was UP ARROW*/){
/*CODE TO MAKE MOVE FORWARD HERE*/
}else if(/*KEY WAS DOWN ARROW*/{
/*CODE TO MAKE MOVE DOWN HERE*/
} etc...
```

inside of that `while(true)` loop. This way, you will be able to use ONE file to capture all keyboard data. So, it would look something similar to this

```
while(true){
//read key input
if(/*key was UP ARROW*/){
    /*CODE TO MAKE MOVE FORWARD HERE*/
    }else if(/*KEY WAS DOWN ARROW*/{
    /*CODE TO MAKE MOVE DOWN HERE*/
    } etc...
}
```

This should do what you need. You already said you have the code to move it, so this shouldn't take long to transfer over.

Try reading more about it here https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/robots/controlling-your-robot-wireless-keyboard This should help you immensely

Comment: Alao, make sure you are using correct Python syntax. Its been awhile for me and this may not syntatically correct, though the idea stands.

Comment: Also, you may want to code in a key for stop. Just a good suggestion.

Comment: This is exactly what I want however I still do not know the actual text for the keys I want I will try and past my code and you can see what I have so far and where I have gone wtong

Comment: So right now your separate files only move the robot, they do not take in keyboard input?

Comment: exactly they move it but done take in keyboard input

Comment: this is what iv been trying but still frows up errors

Comment: while True:
        char = getch()

        if(char=="w"):
                mot1.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD)
                mot2.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD)
                mot3.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD)
                mot4.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD)

Comment: if your up for it send me an email to georgedurell@gmail.com

Comment: and ill send you the whole code and you can show me where iv gone wrong.... if it helps

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/bot/botkeyboardwith sys.py", line 30, in <module>
    ch = getch()
  File "/root/bot/botkeyboardwith sys.py", line 23, in getch
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
NameError: global name 'termios' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Ive edited my answer with a link. That should get you where you need to be.